# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

while retrieving json data using ionic 2
here is the link  http://areeef.unaux.com/php/platforms.php

here is the code i am using to get json data

```
constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http) {

this.http.get('http://areeef.unaux.com/php/platforms.php').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
}); }
```

when i run the same php code in local host then i can run the app without any error. but in online sever it is giving the error mentioned above
so is that a problem of the server or error in my code?

Comment: Looks like the API is expecting a `Cookie` header: when I give it the value `__test=53a7c54a89820a57b1404151ef11576c` in Postman, then I can get the JSON (otherwise, I get some HTML with following message: "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support"). I guess a match is performed with the actual cookie that is set for domain areeef.unaux.com (can't understand how it's set though), so this specific value may not work for you. This looks like a CSRF protection IMO.

Comment: Try this 

 this.http.get(url,body,options).map(res=> (res['_body'])).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
});

Comment: what i have to write for body and options?

Comment: Am sorry if you're using get no need of options and body but I hope you're sending some data via URL.

Comment: i checked with a valid json file..but still it is giving me the same error. so may be  a problem with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with the code. The problem is because your server not returning valid JSON.

Check the API's behaviour using postman plugin. I have checked it and it returning invalid JSON-

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

So, get your api working on postman first.

Comment: i checked with a valid json file..but still it is giving me the same error. so may be  a problem with the server.

Comment: It may be because of  server  configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally caused by the server returning non JSON data. In this case, the PHP script could be returning an error message in form of HTML which will cause an error. The best approach for such errors is to debug the PHP script independently or accommodate the possibility of getting both html and JSON data on the client side.